# Removing keys from a small dataframe which are present in a larger dataframe in pyspark/spark

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark, query-optimization, anti-join

I have 2 dataframes,

1. df_A is having size in few megabytes, primary key P
2. df_B is having size in few gigabytes, also has this row P

How can i efficiently remove all records from df_A whose P are present in df_B?

Currently I use naive spark sql syntax to get this done without any optimisations

```py
df_A.createOrReplaceTempView('df_A_table')
df_B.createOrReplaceTempView('df_B_table')

spark.sql("""
select
*
from df_A_table
where df_A_table.P not in (
    select P from df_B_table
)
""")
```

Does broadcast join make sense here, if so how does it help here (i am just guessing it might work, but not sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all records from `df_A` whose `P` are present in `df_B` can be accomplished by performing a `left anti-join` between df_A and df_B.

Here is an example below where tables A and B can be left anti joined on P:

```
df_A:
+---+---+
|  P|  Q|
+---+---+
|  1| 10|
|  2| 20|
|  3| 30|
|  4| 40|
+---+---+

df_B:
+---+---+
|  P|  S|
+---+---+
|  1|100|
|  3|300|
|  5|500|
+---+---+
```

Typically for a join (or antijoin) between tables A and B, pyspark will need to shuffle the data of both tables, and put the portions of both tables with matching values for P into the same nodes. However, shuffling a large table is expensive, so a broadcast join splits up the larger table into different nodes (without shuffling it), and the entire smaller table is "broadcast" or copied to each node to be joined with each piece of the larger table.

In your case, since df_B is much larger than df_A, we broadcast the smaller dataframe to send it to all nodes to be joined with the larger dataframe (which is split across all nodes):

```
df_A.join(
  F.broadcast(df_B),
  df_A.P == df_B.P,
  'leftanti'
).select(
    df_A.P, df_A.Q
)
```

Result:

```
+---+---+
|  P|  Q|
+---+---+
|  2| 20|
|  4| 40|
+---+---+
```

Comment: hello i am really sorry for wrong phrasing in question, my question in title was
How can i efficiently remove all records from df_A whose P *are present* in df_B?
but I incorrectly wrote the earlier in the body

Comment: @jeea oh i see – in that case you want to do a left anti join. i've updated my answer

Comment: thank you so normal broadcast is working but how do they do it
lets say i have 3 executors and 3 partitions of B end up in different executors
and A is broadcast to all 3. Now does spark while combining the three broadcast A (A1, A2, A3) dataframes into single one check the common rows in each of them (intersect(A1, A2, A3)) ??
thank yu

Comment: @jeea yes, the default behavior of a broadcast join is to remove default duplicate rows. so your final result would be something like `intersect(A1 join B1, A2 join B2, A3 join B3)` where `A1 = A2 = A3 = A`